# Compositions of polynomials with themselves and prime numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers

Suppose that we start with some polynomial $P_1(n)=\sum_{i=0}^ka_in^i$ and define $P_2(n)$ as $P_2(n)=P_1(P_1(n)$) and, more generally, $P_m(n)=P_{m-1}(P_1(n))$.

I do not know how much is known of can the sequence $m \to P_m(n)$ have an infinite number of primes for some choices of $P_1$ and $n$ and it seems to me as quite a hard a question, but I would like to know at least this:

> Does there exist some polynomial $P_1$ and some natural number $n$ so that the sequence $m \to P_m(n)$ consists of prime numbers only?

Comment: My guess is that if it is true, then nobody know how to prove it.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Expect the unexpected.

Comment: If you drop the infinite number, it becomes mostly trivial: take a polynomial $P_1$ that merely does a permutation among a few primes, and start your sequence at one of them.

Comment: What about $P(n)=n$ ? :) If the iteration produces infinite many distinct values, it would be more than surprising if ALL these values could be prime numbers. And I agree Jose's comment. A proof that a specific polynomial does the job (if existent) would be almost certain out of reach. Note that it is even unknown whether $n^2+1$ contains infinite many primes.

Comment: @AntoinePalAdeen In some sense, almost every question about prime numbers is harder than Goldbach+ Riemann hypothesis + abc + twin primes. The only tool we have to make some realistic conjectures on such sequences is the random model for the primes. See for example [Apostol's book](https://fr.scribd.com/document/360267644/Tom-Apostol-Introduction-To-Analytic-Number-Theory-pdf) listing the very few topics which lead to interesting theorems about primes.